# Combining Multiple Dataframes with Unique Name

Tags: python, pandas

I have for example 2 data frames with user and their rating for each place such as:

**Dataframe 1:**

```
Name    Golden Gate
Adam    1
Susan   4
Mike    5
John    4
```

**Dataframe 2:**

```
Name    Botanical Garden
Jenny   1
Susan   4
Leslie  5
John    3
```

I want to combine them into a single data frame with the result:

**Combined Dataframe:**

```
Name    Golden Gate   Botanical Garden
Adam    1             NA
Susan   4             4
Mike    5             NA
John    4             3
Jenny   NA            1
Leslie  NA            5
```

How to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @CeliusStingher that is a good reference

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform an `outer join` or a concatenation along an axis:

```
final_df = df1.merge(df2,how='outer',on='Name')
```

Output:

```
     Name  Golden Gate  Botanical Garden
0    Adam          1.0               NaN
1   Susan          4.0               4.0
2    Mike          5.0               NaN
3    John          4.0               3.0
4   Jenny          NaN               1.0
5  Leslie          NaN               5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that pandas merge with how='outer' solves the problem. The link provided by @Celius Stingher is useful